# Hash::DisallowedType exception on Rails 3.2.16

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are using honeybadger for app monitoring and tinfoil for scanning security vulnerabilities. Recently I noticed that we got a exception triggered:

```
Hash::DisallowedType: Disallowed type attribute: "yaml"
```

I know that this happens because of a patch that was introduced into rails after a serious security vulnerability. Is it safe to add Hash::DisallowedType to the ignore list in honeybadger so that this will not occur again?

Regards
Rujaun